# Symfony 1.4 User Activity Log and History Plugin Using Doctrine

Tags: symfony-1.4, orangehrm, symfony-plugins

I am going to implement the User Log history into my project (OrangeHRM). I am using Doctrine.I found some plugins for Log and History but those plugins use Propal but I want in doctrine.Is there any plugin for this?

If no then I am going to implement this on every Action (Add/Edit/Delete). This will be take too much time to find and enter code. I want that is there any Event that can tell us the Add/Edit/Delete Status so that I just enter my Log history code in that Event.

Comment: here you can find Events http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/more-with-symfony/1_4/en/08-Advanced-Doctrine-Usage

Comment: there is already a `Versionable` behavior. [Have a look here how to configure and use](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine1/en/latest/en/manual/behaviors.html#versionable).